# Why doesn't this limit exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to compute this limit:
$\lim_{x\to +\infty}x^2-x^2\sqrt{1+\frac{(-1)^x}{x^2}}$
which, according to the results, is not defined; I initially thought about a $\infty - \infty$ form but it looks like I'm missing something...

Comment: "$\infty - \infty$" does not mean anything, consider for example $x_n - y_n$ with $x_n = n$ and $y_n = n$ and with $x_n = n^2$ and $y_n = n$. You have to be careful with "$\infty$" since sometimes it behaves almost like a real number and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: How is defined $(-1)^x$ in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @EmilioNovati Two possible approaches: 1) consider that this could be asking about a limit of a *sequence*, with $x$ ranging over the positive integers. 2) $(-1)^x := e^{i \pi x}$. Both should yield similar results.

Comment: It's not defined for all x, my bad I actually let the whole fraction go to 0 because of the higher infinity order.

Comment: @MikeHaskel If this were a sequence, would the limit change in any way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With $\;x\in\Bbb N\;$ , so that $\;(-1)^x\;$ has a definite meaning within the real numbers:

$$\left(x^2-x^2\sqrt{1+\frac{(-1)^x}{x^2}}\right)\cdot\frac{x^2+x^2\sqrt{1+\frac{(-1)^x}{x^2}}}{x^2+x^2\sqrt{1+\frac{(-1)^x}{x^2}}}=$$$${}$$

$$=\frac{(-1)^{x+1}x^2}{x^2+x^2\sqrt{1+\cfrac{(-1)^x}{x^2}}}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}\begin{cases}\;\;\,\frac12,&x\;\text{is odd}\\{}\\-\frac12,&x\;\text{is even}\end{cases}$$

and thus *the* limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Note first that there's a potential issue with $(-1)^x$ being ambiguous or undefined for non-integer values of $x$. That's not a fundamental problem, however; we can just consider the question as asking about a sequence.

With that in mind, consider we can multiply by the conjugate root:

\begin{align*}
x^2 - x^2\sqrt{1 + \frac{(-1)^x}{x^2}}
&= \frac{x^4 - x^4\left(1 + \frac{(-1)^x}{x^2}\right)}{x^2 + x^2\sqrt{1 + \frac{(-1)^x}{x^2}}} \\
&= \frac{-x^2(-1)^x}{x^2 + x^2\sqrt{1 + \frac{(-1)^x}{x^2}}} \\
&= \frac{-(-1)^x}{1 + \sqrt{1 + \frac{(-1)^x}{x^2}}} \\
&= (-1)^{x+1} \frac{1}{1 + \sqrt{1+\frac{(-1)^x}{x^2}}}
\end{align*}

Notice that $\frac{1}{1 + \sqrt{1+\frac{(-1)^x}{x^2}}}$ is always positive and does not approach 0. Therefore, since the $(-1)^{x+1}$ term out front makes the whole expression alternate signs, the limit does not exist.